# MPI errors "MPI_ERR_IN_STATUS" and "BadPickleGet" in OpenMDAO when running external codes in parallel with many processors

Tags: mpi, openmdao

The OpenMDAO problem that I'm running is quite complicated so I don't think it would be helpful to post the entire script. However, the basic setup is that my problem root is a ParallelFDGroup (not actually finite differencing for now--just running the problem once) that contains a few normal components as well as a parallel group. The parallel group is responsible for running 56 instances of an external code (one component per instance of the code). Strangely, when I run the problem with 4-8 processors, everything seems to work fine (sometimes even works with 10-12 processors). But when I try to use more processors (20+), I fairly consistently get the errors below. It provides two tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opt_5mw.py", line 216, in <module>
    top.setup()   #call setup
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 644, in setup
    self.root._setup_vectors(param_owners, impl=self._impl, alloc_derivs=alloc_derivs)
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/group.py", line 476, in _setup_vectors
    self._u_size_lists = self.unknowns._get_flattened_sizes()
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/petsc_impl.py", line 204, in _get_flattened_sizes
    return self.comm.allgather(sizes)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1291, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.allgather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109194)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 746, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_allgather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:48575)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_IN_STATUS: error code in status

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opt_5mw.py", line 216, in <module>
    top.setup()   #call setup
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 644, in setup
    self.root._setup_vectors(param_owners, impl=self._impl, alloc_derivs=alloc_derivs)
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/group.py", line 476, in _setup_vectors
    self._u_size_lists = self.unknowns._get_flattened_sizes()
  File "/home/austinherrema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/petsc_impl.py", line 204, in _get_flattened_sizes
    return self.comm.allgather(sizes)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1291, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.allgather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109194)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 749, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_allgather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:48609)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 191, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.loadv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:41957)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 143, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.load (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:41248)
cPickle.BadPickleGet: 65
```

I am running under Ubuntu with OpenMDAO 1.7.3. I have tried running with both mpirun.openmpi (OpenRTE) 1.4.3 and mpirun (Open MPI) 1.4.3 and have gotten the same result in each case.

I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpi4py/hGhdFMMKsM8) that seems to suggest that there is something wrong with the MPI installation. But if this were the case, it strikes me as strange that the problem would work for a small number of processors but not with a larger number. I also can run a relatively simple OpenMDAO problem (no external codes) with 32 processors without incident.

Because the traceback references OpenMDAO unknowns, I wondered if there are limitations on the size of OpenMDAO unknowns. In my case, each external code component has a few dozen array outputs that can be up to 50,000-60,000 elements each. Might that be problematic? Each external code component also reads the same set of input files. Could that be an issue as well? I have tried to ensure that read and write access is defined properly but perhaps that's not enough.

Any suggestions about what might be culprit in this situation are appreciated.

EDIT: I should add that I have tried running the problem without actually running the external codes (i.e. the components in the parallel group are called and set up but the external subprocesses are never actually created) and the problem persists.

EDIT2: I have done some more debugging on this issue and thought I should share the little that I have discovered. If I strip the problem down to only the parallel group containing the external code instances, the problem persists. However, if I reduce the components in the parallel group to basically nothing--just a print function for setup and for solve_nonlinear--then the problem can successfully "run" with a large number of processors. I started adding setup lines back in one by one to see what would create problems. I ran into issues when trying to add many large unknowns to the components. I can actually still add just a single large unknown--for example, this works:

```
self.add_output('BigOutput', shape=[100000])
```

But when I try to add too many large outputs like below, I get errors:

```
for i in range(100):
    outputname = 'BigOutput{0}'.format(i)
    self.add_output(outputname, shape=[100000])
```

Sometimes I just get a general segmentation violation error from PETSc. Other times I get a fairly length traceback that is too long to post here--I'll post just the beginning in case it provides any helpful clues:

```
*** glibc detected *** python2.7: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f21204f5010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7da26)[0x7f2285f0ca26]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0(sqlite3_free+0x4f)[0x7f2269b7754f]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0(+0x1cbbc)[0x7f2269b87bbc]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0(+0x54d6c)[0x7f2269bbfd6c]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0(+0x9d31f)[0x7f2269c0831f]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0(sqlite3_step+0x1bf)[0x7f2269be261f]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so(pysqlite_step+0x2d)[0x7f2269e4306d]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so(_pysqlite_query_execute+0x661)[0x7f2269e404b1]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8942)[0x7f2286c6a5a2]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x86c3)[0x7f2286c6a323]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x86c3)[0x7f2286c6a323]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89e)[0x7f2286c6b1ce]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x797e1)[0x7f2286be67e1]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f2286bb6dc3]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x5c54f)[0x7f2286bc954f]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f2286bb6dc3]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7f2286c60d63]
/home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x136652)[0x7f2286ca3652]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f2286957e9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f2285f8236d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9706352                            /home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/python2.7
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:03 9706352                            /home/austinherrema/miniconda2/bin/python2.7
00aca000-113891000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                 [heap]
7f21107d6000-7f2241957000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
etc...
```

Comment: you're probably running out of memory with a lot of unknowns... there is a limit to 32 bit math.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to guess whats going on here, but if it works for a small number of processors and not on larger ones one guess might be that the issue shows up when you use more than one node, and data has to get transfered across the network. I have seen bad MPI compilations that behaved this way. Things would work if I kept the job to one node, but broke on more than one.

The traceback shows that you're not even getting through setup. So its not likely to be anything in your external code or any other components run method.

If you're running on a cluster, are you compiling your own MPI? You usually need to compile very with very specific options/libraries for any kind of HPC library. But most HPC systems provide modules you can load that have mpi pre-compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I hadn't fully thought through the fact that it didn't even get through setup so that may be helpful. We are actually running on our own machine so we haven't had to do anything too crazy in regards to MPI compilation. Just installing vanilla MPI with apt-get. Again, if the issue were due to a problem with MPI itself I would expect it to behave this way for any problem using a larger number of processors, right? But that's not the case. I can run a simple omdao optimization problem on 32 processors no problem.

Comment: After some more experimentation, you may be right about the cross-node issue. We definitely seem to have fewer problems when using only a single node's-worth of processors (although it's hard to know which processors are being used for which attempts). Still doesn't explain why I can run a simple problem with the full number of processors, but still seems relevant. Maybe an mpi4py problem...

Comment: @aherrema One quick thing, probably you've already checked, but this is very important when using mpi4py since you could face strange behavior later: did you check that the mpi4py that you use is built against the exact same type (OpenMPI, MPICH,etc.) and version of MPI library that you load in your environment? I had once an issue caused by that once, but I don't know if it applies in your case. You can check with:

from mpi4py import MPI  

name, version = MPI.get_vendor()  
  
or just  
 
print MPI.get_vendor()

Comment: @fedepad I appreciate the suggestion and the instructions for checking mpi4py version. When running MPI.get_vender() I get ('Open MPI', (1, 4, 3)), which appears to be consistent with the OpenMPI 1.4.3 that I'm running. So I don't think that's it. But thank you!

Comment: Added a bit more info in original post. Issue seems to be somehow tied to unknowns...